# How to run Application with multiple parameters?

Tags: c#, windows

```
public static void RunProcess(string FileName, string Arguments, ProcessWindowStyle WindowStyle, bool WaitforExit)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Runnig the process :- File name- " + FileName.ToString() + "argumetns- " + Arguments.ToString() + "windowStyle- " + WindowStyle.ToString() + "WaitForExit- " + WaitforExit.ToString());
    Process MyProcess = new Process();
    MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = FileName;
    MyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;
    MyProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = WindowStyle;
    MyProcess.Start();
    if (WaitforExit)
        MyProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

Here Arguments are having some spaces too.!!

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: it is throwing the error that invalid arguments.

Comment: Can you show us what the exact arguments are you are passing to this method?

Comment: it is not static sometimes it will have some spaces some times not? Is spaces are creating the problem?

Comment: Your problem is almost certainly in the arguments argument, arguments with spaces or other illegal characters, or what you are passing is illegal as far as the app you are calling is concerned, which is a different problem entirely...

Comment: Some useful advice, don't use Pascal case for variables in method parameter names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about spaces in arguments in general, then you need to wrap the arguments with double qoutes:

```
MyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"this argument has spaces\"";
```

So make sure that happens to the arguments that get passed on to your method.

Comment: So, i first need to look to my arguments if it has any spaces that need to wrap it with quotes.!!right?

Comment: Yes. You can choose to always use the double quotes, even without spaces, if that helps. But as soon as there are spaces in the arguments you definitely need to use the double quotes.

Comment: Ok...got it!Great man!

Comment: NB this will only cope with one argument. Also it will go wrong if teh argument (or arguments) have a double quote in them e.g. --height=6"3'

Comment: yeah, funny characters will need to be escaped properly of course, I only mentioned spaces since that was the question/problem of the OP.

Comment: adding double quotes to each arguments solved the issue. but for special chars how can i take care of those?